# I Cannot move my meshes any more whats goimg on?

Tags: mesh, transform-orientation

I try to move meshes but the just won't translate. I don't know if I hit any key. The translation values just vary between 0 and - 0 on any axis

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

The most common issues may be either you have some transform channels locked, see your options bar (<kbd>N</kbd>) :

[image]

Or you have a Limit constraint on your object, in which case you just have to delete it :

[image]

Or your transform properties are driven, in which case you just have to right-click → Delete Drivers:

[image]

If it neither those issues, please provide more info in your topic, as well as your .blend file.